# How do I connect a question to my userid

Tags: support, migration, user-accounts

My first question [Highlight an equation within an align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13681/highlight-an-equation-within-an-align-environment) was migrated over before I got set up with my tex.SE account. How do I connect this to my account?

It would be helpful for me to have it my list of questions as I use that as a reference, and also allow me to accept the answer.

Comment: I think [Why Tex site doesn't associate with stackexchange in my profile?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/why-tex-site-doesnt-associate-with-stackexchange-in-my-profile) will help. You need to have an registered account on the other site as well AFAIK.

Comment: Not sure what to do. I looked at the link and was not able to find the **Clear All Associations** button referred to there. Plus when I go to stackoverflow, this question does not show up there in my list of questions.

Comment: Just go to http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4301/peter-grill?tab=accounts and scroll all the way down. Are you sure your account at stackoverflow was registered? Otherwise you need to register it first, anyway. The original question there got deleted so I have trouble finding your user page there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally email the address at the bottom of every page for such matters.

I reattached this question to your account.